# Edit multiple vertices of different features simultaneously

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2

I am using ArcGIS 10.2.2 and would like to edit multiple vertices of different features simultaneously.  For example, I have a man hole with three laterals - is it possible to select all four features and move the end points of the laterals and manhole node at the same time.  See sketch below - move manhole and lateral end points to blue "+".  I have tried using topology but I am only able to get it to move the manhole and one line segment of the three.

[image: Move MH and laterials to "+"]

I need to use this ability to adjust thousands of such feature combinations to newer high accuracy imagery I just received.  Moving each of the multiple vertices one at a time will be painfully slow.

Comment: This might help: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//01m600000065000000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Topology/Map needs to be created/set first then

> you can use the Topology Edit tool to select edges in a topology. Once
>   you have selected them, you can move, modify, and reshape them. If you
>   want to select multiple edges that form a path so you can reshape them
>   all at the same time, you can use the Topology Edit Trace tool or
>   simply hold down the left mouse button using the regular Topology Edit
>   tool.

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Selecting_topology_edges/01mm00000007000000/

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Creating_a_map_topology/01mm0000000r000000/

Comment: Thanks that was what I had tried before but it did not work.  Turned out is was the editing sticky move setting.  It was set vey high to prevent accidental movement of features.  Lowered it to 1000 pixels and now I can use topology as long as I initially move the intersection more than 1000 pixels and then position to the correct location before releasing the mouse button.

Answer (score 1):

Are these features all in the same database? If so, opening an edit session and editing all the layers at once, you should be able to drag a box using the edit tool over the intersection and move all at once.

Comment: This moves the features in their entirety and not just the single common vertex.